# Microsoft Report is Repeating in Multiple Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, microsoft-reporting, reportviewerformvc

this is my first time for using Microsoft Report.I am working on MVC5 project (Visual Studio 2015) . I have add rdlc file into my project , and put background image to it . When I run it on the browser it repeated in multiple sections (same report in multiple pages) . I want to display my report only in one page (first page) . please advice , thanks

Comment: Do you put the image in the report's body?

Comment: yes , first the image was repeated since i adjust the resolution of the image . Now the page repeat it self

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the image only in the first page, you have to put it the report's header or use a [Conditional Visibility control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd354976.aspx) in the image to show only when page=1